# Why the Memory leak existing after release?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

I have a code snippet as below:

```
NSURL *fonturl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:gdbPath];
CGDataProviderRef fontDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fonturl);
CGFontRef newFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProvider);
NSString *newFontName = CFBridgingRelease(CGFontCopyPostScriptName(newFont));
CGDataProviderRelease(fontDataProvider);
CFErrorRef fonterror;
CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(newFont, &fonterror);
CGFontRelease(newFont);
```

Here I get a memory leak when I worked with Xcode Instruments. I tried many times to get rid of this with several alternatives. But I could not escape from memory leaks.

Comment: Which line exactly does it says is leaking? What kind of struct/object? There are 2 ZZCreate, and I saw the two ZZRelease, so it should be good.

Comment: @Larme : NSString *newFontName = CFBridgingRelease(CGFontCopyPostScriptName(newFont));

Comment: Are you using ARC or not? What do you do with `newFontName`?

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes, am using ARC.     UIFont * finalFont = [UIFont fontWithName:newFontName size:fontSize];

Comment: It looks right. The ownership of the font name string should be passed to `newFontName` and ARC should release it when done. Are you seeing the leaks in the simulator or a real device? Try a real device if you aren't.